# Where can I find good examples of using generics in C#

Tags: c#, .net, generics, open-source

Generics is a complicated topic. There are generic classes, generic methods, different type of restrictions. One generic class may have inner generic class etc. So, it would be nice to see a project which extensively uses them. I want to see where they are truly powerful.

Comment: They aren't "truly powerful". They are specifically designed to *not* be powerful, to be a convenience tool to allow better compile-time type checking, but they lack everything that would make them "powerful".

Comment: http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/

Comment: You're interested in using them? or how to create your own ?

Comment: I am interested in creating my own generic classes.

Answer (score 2):

you can start with the msdn Library.. check the links below

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Regards

Answer (score 2):

I would like to recommend a book to understand Generics [C# in Depth](http://csharpindepth.com/)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the collection classes in the .NET framework source:  http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx